Asymptotic distribution of $u$-like statistic
Let $X_{1,1}, X_{1,2}, ..., X_{1,n_1}$ and $X_{2,1}, X_{2,2}, ..., X_{2,n_2}$ be two independent collections of independent and identically distributed random variables. Define: $$\tilde U_{i;n_1,n_2} := \frac{1}{2n_i}\sum_{k=1}^{n_i}\sum_{\iota=1}^2\sum_{\ell=1}^{n_\iota}\operatorname{sgn}(X_{i,k} - X_{\iota,\ell}).$$
Here $\operatorname{sgn}$ is the sign function (i.e., $\operatorname{sgn}(x) = -1$ if $x < 0$, $\operatorname{sgn}(x) = 0$ if $x = 0$, and $\operatorname{sgn}(x) = 1$ if $x>0$). Question: what is the asymptotic distribution of $\tilde U_{i;n_1,n_2}$?
It is striking that this statistic looks like a u-statistic. A u-statistic $U$ with symmetric kernel $h$ is defined as $$ U := \frac{1}{{n_1 \choose m_1}{n_2 \choose m_2}}\sum h(X_{1,i_1}, X_{1,i_2}, ..., X_{1,i_{m_1}}, X_{2,j_1}, X_{2,j_2}, ..., X_{2,j_{m_2}})$$ with the sum ranging over all ${n_1 \choose m_1}{n_2 \choose m_2}$ sets of subscripts such that $1\leq i_1 < i_2 <... < i_{m_1} \leq n_1$ and $1\leq j_1 < j_2 < ... < j_{m_2} \leq n_2$.
However, I fail to rewrite $\tilde U_{i;n_1,n_2}$ in terms of a u-statistic. The problem is the tripple sum and the fact that I have only $\frac{1}{2n_i}$ as a factor in front of the sums. Furthermore, $\operatorname{sgn}$ is not symmetric so it does not meet the requirements of the definition of a kernel of a u-statistic.
Is $\tilde U_{i;n_1,n_2}$ even a u-statistic? Maybe this is not the right approach, and another approach is necessary to derive the asymptotic distribution of $\tilde U_{i;n_1,n_2}$. I know that the inner two sums are related to order statistics. However, I am not allowed to use this relation when deriving the asymptotic distribution.

For $\iota=i$, $$\sum_{k=1}^{n_i}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n_\iota}\operatorname{sgn}(X_{i,k}-X_{\iota,\ell})=\sum_{k=1}^{n_i}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n_i}\operatorname{sgn}(X_{i,k}-X_{i,\ell})=0$$
which contributes nothing to $\tilde{U}_{i;n_1,n_2}$.
For $\iota\neq i$, $$U_{n_1,n_2}=\frac1{n_1n_2}\sum_{k=1}^{n_i}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n_\iota}\operatorname{sgn}(X_{i,k}-X_{\iota,\ell})$$ is a two-sample $U$-statistic (the kernel is symmetric for within-sample permutations of arguments).
So $\tilde{U}_{i;n_1,n_2}$ is just a rescaled version of $U_{n_1,n_2}$. For regularity, we need $n_i/(n_1+n_2)$ to converge to a proper limit.
I think this is just a two-sample Wilcoxon-Mann–Whitney test.

Thank you very much for your answer, and in particular for pointing out that some of terms are 0. I did oversee that. However, there are still two things that are unclear to me: 1. What do you mean by "within-sample" permutations? and 2. $\tilde U_{i;n_1,n_2}$ is a rescaled version of your $U_{n_1,n_2}$ in the sense that $U_{n_1,n_2} = \frac{2}{n_2}\tilde U_{i;n_1,n_2}$, correct?

@SydAmerikaner For "within-sample permutation", I mean the same thing as in your definition of two-sample $U$ statistic. If subscripts $i$ index sample $1$ and subscripts $j$ index sample $2$, then any $i$ can be permuted arbitrarily with other other $i$ and any $j$ can be permutated arbitrarily with any other $j$. But we cannot swap any $i$ in sample 1 with any $j$ sample $2$. Here the $m_i=1$ and $m_j=1$. So $h(x;y)=\operatorname{sgn}(x-y)$ but we do not need $h(x;y)=h(y;x)$. (I usually use ; to separate indices from the different samples and , to separate indices within samples).

@SydAmerikaner For "rescaled", you are essentially correct (except for the minor typo).

Thanks for clarifying. Just one more question regarding the re-scaling for the case $i=1$: under the regularity condition you mention, $\sqrt{n_1 + n_2}U_{1;n_1,n_2}$ converges in distribution to a centered normal distribution. For the scaled version, we have $\sqrt{n_1+n_2}\tilde U_{1;n_1,n_2} = \sqrt{n_1+n_2}\frac{2n_2}{2n_2}\tilde U_{1;n_1,n_2}=\sqrt{n_1+n_2}\frac{n_2}{2}U_{1;n_1,n_2}$. The factor $\frac{n_2}2$ blows up the convergence. Or am I mixing things up here?

@Syd I agree. But it does not seem to matter much practically. When we talk about any asymptotic distribution, I think we implicitly assume that a proper standardization (e.g., scaling) has been employed.

So, I see. Let's say I have a consistent estimator $\xi$ of the asymptotic variance $\sqrt{n_1 + n_2}\frac{n_2}2U_{i;n_1,n_2}$ then $\sqrt{n_1+n_2}\frac{n_2}2\frac{U_{i;n_1,n_2}}{\sqrt\xi}$ would converge to a standard normal distribution. The "problematic term" $\frac{n_2}2$ will appear in $\sqrt\xi$ too, and thus, the term will cancel. Is this what you mean?

@Syd What I mean is that, in practice, e.g., when doing an asymptotic test, we'll either compare $\sqrt{n_1+n_2}\frac{n_2}{2}\frac{U_{i:n_1,n_2}}{\sqrt{\xi}}$ with $z_\alpha$, or compare $U_{i:n_1,n_2}$ with $\frac{\sqrt{\xi}}{\sqrt{n_n1+n_2}n_2/2}z_\alpha$.  They lead to identical conclusions and make no practical difference.

Thanks for clarifying.
